# How to create multiple nested while-loops in a big while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, nested

In very basic terms, I have a big while loop, with many while loops. In the code part I will give more detail but lets say I want to create a big loop that repeats itself until the condition is met and the sub loops are options for the user of the code to choose from.

In my code, I created the big while loop, along with 4 sub loops, but for some reason, when I move on to the next loops, I cant make the user access the previous loops. Help?

This is for JAVA btw... thanks

I will simplify the code a lot to give the general idea...

Lets say I do the 'A' loop... i can do it multiple times in a row, however, if I move on to the next sub loops, i cant access A anymore? Please help...

[image: access my code here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a switch case inside your while loop.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/switch_statement_in_java.htm